# difference between dune utop and utop

Tags: ocaml, variant, polymorphic-variants

If I load the following code in `utop`, after `#require "mparser"`, it is accepted in the top level and give the signature below

```
open MParser

let infix p op = Infix (p |>> (fun _ a b -> (`Binop (op, a, b))), Assoc_left)

let operators =
  [
    [
      infix (char '*') `Mul;
      infix (char '/') `Div;
    ];
    [
      infix (char '+') `Add;
      infix (char '-') `Sub;
    ];
  ]

let decimal = many1_chars digit |>> int_of_string

let term = (decimal |>> fun i -> `Int i)
let expr s  =  expression operators term s

let rec calc = function
  | `Int i -> i
  | `Binop (op, a, b) ->
      match op with
        | `Add -> calc a + calc b
        | `Sub -> calc a - calc b
        | `Mul -> calc a * calc b
        | `Div -> calc a / calc b
```

accepted by `utop` as

```
val infix :
  ('a, 'b) MParser.t ->
  'c -> ([> `Binop of 'c * 'd * 'd ] as 'd, 'b) MParser.operator = <fun>
val operators :
  (_[> `Binop of _[> `Add | `Div | `Mul | `Sub ] * 'a * 'a | `Int of int ]
   as 'a, unit)
  MParser.operator list list =
  [[Infix (<fun>, Assoc_left); Infix (<fun>, Assoc_left)];
   [Infix (<fun>, Assoc_left); Infix (<fun>, Assoc_left)]]
val decimal : (int, unit) MParser.t = <fun>
val term : ([> `Int of int ], unit) MParser.t = <fun>
val expr :
  unit MParser.state ->
  (_[> `Binop of _[> `Add | `Div | `Mul | `Sub ] * 'a * 'a | `Int of int ]
   as 'a, unit)
  MParser.reply = <fun>
val calc :
  ([< `Binop of [< `Add | `Div | `Mul | `Sub ] * 'a * 'a | `Int of int ] as 'a) ->
  int = <fun>
```

Now, if I try to load with `dune utop` a library containing this code as a file/module, I received the following error :

```
~$ dune utop lib
      ocamlc lib/.lib.objs/lib__VariantExemple.{cmi,cmo,cmt} (exit 2)
(cd _build/default && /usr/local/bin/ocamlc.opt -w @a-4-29-40-41-42-44-45-48-58-59-60-40 -strict-sequence -strict-formats -short-paths -keep-locs -g -bin-annot -I lib/.lib.objs -I lib/.lib.objs/.private -I /Users/nrolland/.opam/system/lib/bytes -I /Users/nrolland/.opam/system/lib/mparser -I /Users/nrolland/.opam/system/lib/re -I /Users/nrolland/.opam/system/lib/re/perl -I /Users/nrolland/.opam/system/lib/seq -no-alias-deps -opaque -open Lib -o lib/.lib.objs/lib__VariantExemple.cmo -c -impl lib/variantExemple.ml)
File "lib/variantExemple.ml", line 5, characters 4-13:
Error: The type of this expression,
       (_[> `Binop of _[> `Add | `Div | `Mul | `Sub ] * 'a * 'a | `Int of int ]
        as 'a, '_weak1)
       operator list list, contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

It looks like there are some type annotation missing.
I am not too familiar with polymorphic variant type and , is there an obvious solution out ?

I was hoping that sticking the signature part given by `utop` in an interface would work, but it does not seem to be valid in a `.mli` file

**Edit** : the simple solution is to add a *closed* type annotation.

```
let operators : ([ `Binop of [ `Add | `Div | `Mul | `Sub ] * 'a * 'a | `Int of int ] as 'a, unit) operator list list  =
```

I am not sure if there is a reason for why an interactive session and a `dune utop lib` one-shot loading should behave differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have  `_` in front of your types, which suggest your type is [weakly polymorphic](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/polymorphism.html#sec52), and the compiler refuse to let such things live in a compiled object.

you can get the same result with the mwe :

```
let store = ref None
```

The toplevel is ok with that as it can be resolved to a monomorphic type later if you evaluate something like `store:= Some1`, which "monomorphise" the type from `_a option ref` to `int option ref`